# $xz_x-yz_y=z\left(x,y\right)\text{ for }y=1,\:z=3x$ - Is my solution right?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$xz_x-yz_y=z\left(x,y\right)\:for\:y=1,\:z=3x$

$\frac{dx}{x}=-\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z}$

$\frac{dx}{x}=-\frac{dy}{y}$

$=> xy\:=\:C_1$

$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dz}{z}$

$=> \frac{x}{z}=C_2$

$C_1=f\left(C_2\right)$

$xy=f\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)$

$=> f\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)=\frac{z}{3}\cdot 1=\frac{z}{3}$

$\frac{z}{3}=xy\:\iff z=3xy$

Comment: If we plug in to the original equation, we get $x(3y) - y(3x) = 3xy$, which is not true for all $x$ and $y$, so it can't be an answer...

Comment: So where's the mistake?

Comment: Plugging in the initial conditions gives $f(\frac{1}{3}) = x$. But this is impossible, so you need to try the other implicit function $f(xy) = \frac{x}{z}$. Or, we can say that if plugging in initial conditions gives a constant value for $C_1$ or $C_2$, that means that variable is truly constant over all $(x,y)$ in the domain, not just for the initial assumption related to it. So in this case, since $C_2 = \frac{1}{3}$ at the initial condition, $\frac{x}{z} = \frac{1}{3}$ everywhere.

Comment: Ah ok thanks I'll remember this

Answer (score 1):

From

$$
F(C_1,C_2) = 0,\  \ \exists f\  |\  C_2 = f(C_1)
$$

now

$$
\frac xz = f(xy)\Rightarrow z = x g(xy)
$$

and with the boundary conditions

$$
3x = x g(x)\Rightarrow g(x) = 3\Rightarrow z = 3x
$$

Comment: You know I always have a hard time to decide if I should calculate it with C1=f(C2) or C2=f(C1). Is there a rule of thumb?

Comment: Since $f$ exists, choose the most convenient.

Comment: What does it mean "convenient"?

Comment: In one side you have the independent variable $z$ and in the other side you have only dependent variables $x,y$ what to choose to the left?